# Filtering the default avatar list

Tags: php, gravatar

I'm using the `avatar_defaults` filter hook to filter the default avatar list. For example:

```
function my_avatar_defaults( $avatar_defaults ) {
    $avatar_defaults['http://example.com/foo.png'] = __( 'Foo' );
    return $avatar_defaults;
}
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'my_avatar_defaults' );
```

This works because if I visit Settings > Discussion and then scroll down, I can see Foo has been added as a default avatar option. See the following screenshot for an example:

[image: Default avatar list of options]

The problem is the `src` attribute of the image displayed next to Foo. It seems to be making a call to Gravatar. Here's an example of the source code I'm getting for the image next to Foo:

```
<img src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/efaeb0e0be9922051a1c4ccce766a141?s=32&d=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo.png%3Fs%3D32&r=G&forcedefault=1" />
```

How can I ensure the `src` attribute points to my image URL instead of the Gravatar URL (which seems to have my image's URL inside it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it correctly.

The call to gravatar.com passes the location of your custom image so that WP can load it. Take a look at the query string in the src, you'll see your image location.  That's how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why does WP need to load the image via Gravatar though?

Comment: That's just the way it works. Gravatar is owned by Automattic, and is part of WordPress.com so that might have something to do with it: http://blog.gravatar.com/2013/04/03/gravatar-and-wordpress-com-together-forever/

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't think calling Gravatar each time is ideal but as you say, it's just the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

Two notes:

1. [`get_avatar()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2093) is a "pluggable" function. That means, that you can write a plugin to hold a new function named `get_avatar()`, which then will overwrite the original function used by WP.
2. `get_avatar()` also has a filter

   ```
   return apply_filters( 'get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt );
   ```

   that you can use to change the return value:

   ```
   add_filter( 'get_avatar', function( $html, $id, $size, $default, $alt )
   {
       // apply some changes here
       return $html;
   }, 10, 5 );
   ```

   and that means that you can simply change the *output* as well and remove the `src` call to "Gravatar" so that it doesn't happen.

Comment: This also changes the default avatars on the discussion settings page